Proof of ripple voltage of capacitor filter?
From Electronic Devices and Circuit Theory by Robert L. Boylestad:

To get an equation for ripple voltage, the book wrote, $$\frac{V_{r(p-p)}}{T_1}=\frac{V_m}{\frac{T}{4}}$$
How did they come up with this equation?

Please add a citation for the book and where the diagram came from.

Plague, you have neglected to include the calculation for $T_1$.

From which page was this taken? || If the input is a sine as shown, what does that suggest about the value at T1, given the ratio as shown?
